# Passing variable to gcp-build method in package.json when deploying on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, environment-variables, next.js, package.json

I have successfully deployed a nextjs site to google app engine, however I want to pass through a env_variable to app.yaml to set a production and staging build.

I can't see how to do this in the GAE documentation and the env_variables don't seem to get sent through to the `gcp-build` command.

See my config below:

```
# app.yaml

runtime: nodejs
env: flex
service: ss-test

env_variables:
  SS_ENV: 'production-test'
```

```
# package.json
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "node server.js",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production node server.js",
    "gcp-build": "next build", <<<<< I want to pass through the SS_ENV variable from app.yaml here
    "deploy:production": "gcloud app deploy"
  },
  ...
}
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong, or is this not possible this way?

Thanks in advance, been banging my head on a wall for a few hours on this one!
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding your previous answer about cloud build usage.  For the context of your question, I could understand that you were trying to use the "Custom Build Step" option, documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/running-custom-build-step). This is only useful when handling and make dependencies available during deployment, before the app starts.

When using Cloud Build. You can create a specialized Build Step using the gcloud [builder](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/cloud-builders), to deploy your GAE with the required configuration. To know a bit more about the gcloud builder you can read [this](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders/tree/master/gcloud).

The required configuration should be declared on the app.yaml. More info about the app.yaml can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/config/appref).

Comment: Yes this is what I ended up doing. Thanks for the response :)

Answer (score 0):

After research and experimentation, Google Cloud Build is the way to go.